# GETX _CastError was thrown building Obx(has builder, dirty, state: _ObxState#7e686): Null check operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx, flutter-listview

i'm getting this error while using list view.

so i have getx controller like this

```
class RequestMitraController extends GetxController {
  final selectedMitra = [].obs;
}
```

and i'm using this for selected item int view like this whit obx to observe the variable

```
Expanded(
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                itemBuilder: (_, i) {
                                  final selected = false.obs;
                                  return Obx(
                                    () => Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.h),
                                      child: GestureDetector(
                                        onTap: () {
                                          selected.value = !selected.value;
                                          selected.value
                                              ? controller.selectedMitra.add(i)
                                              : controller.selectedMitra
                                                  .remove(i);
                                        },
                                        child: Container(
                                          width: 373.w,
                                          height: 96.h,
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(20.r),
                                            color: selected.value
                                                ? Colors.green
                                                : Colors.grey[300],
                                          ),
                                          child: Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(9.r),
                                            child: Row(
                                              children: [
                                                Container(
                                                  width: 80.w,
                                                  height: 80.h,
                                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            10.r),
                                                    image: DecorationImage(
                                                      image: NetworkImage(
                                                          "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1518791841217-8f162f1e1131?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60"),
                                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                SizedBox(width: 20.w),
                                                Expanded(
                                                  child: Column(
                                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                                        CrossAxisAlignment
                                                            .start,
                                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                                        MainAxisAlignment
                                                            .center,
                                                    children: [
                                                      TextMonserratBold(
                                                        text: "John Doe",
                                                        fontSize: 14.sp,
                                                        textColour: mainBlack,
                                                      ),
                                                      SizedBox(height: 5.h),
                                                      TextMonserratNormal(
                                                        text:
                                                            "Cashier, SPG, Packaging Helper",
                                                        fontSize: 11.sp,
                                                        textColour: mainBlack,
                                                      ),
                                                      SizedBox(height: 5.h),
                                                      Row(
                                                        children: [
                                                          Icon(
                                                            CupertinoIcons
                                                                .star_fill,
                                                            color: mainBlack,
                                                            size: 14.sp,
                                                          ),
                                                          SizedBox(width: 5.w),
                                                          TextMonserratBold(
                                                            text: "4.5",
                                                            fontSize: 14.sp,
                                                            textColour:
                                                                mainBlack,
                                                          ),
                                                          Spacer(),
                                                          Icon(
                                                            CupertinoIcons
                                                                .check_mark_circled,
                                                            color: Colors.green,
                                                            size: 14.sp,
                                                          ),
                                                          SizedBox(width: 5.w),
                                                          TextMonserratNormal(
                                                            text: "Available",
                                                            fontSize: 14.sp,
                                                            textColour:
                                                                mainBlack,
                                                          ),
                                                        ],
                                                      ),
                                                    ],
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                SizedBox(width: 20.w),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                                itemCount: 20,
                              ),
                            ),
```

everything was working fine. but when i use get.toNamed to go to next page

```
 Get.toNamed(
                      Routes.ORDER_SUMMARY,
                      arguments: controller.selectedMitra,
                    );
```

and go back to this page i get this error.

is there any suggestion for my problem since i have no idea how to deal with this :).

`======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building Obx(has builder, dirty, state: _ObxState#7e686):
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was:
Obx Obx:file:///Volumes/DATA/GEBU/client/lib/app/modules/request_mitra/views/request_mitra_view.dart:103:42
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Element.widget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3203:31)
#1      RenderObjectElement.widget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5545:42)
#2      _LayoutBuilderElement.widget (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:61:64)
#3      debugCheckHasMediaQuery.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:229:17)
#4      debugCheckHasMediaQuery (package:flutter/src/widgets/debug.dart:245:4)
#5      MediaQuery.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart:859:12)
#6      ScreenUtil.screenHeight (package:flutter_screenutil/screen_util.dart:74:36)
#7      ScreenUtil.scaleHeight (package:flutter_screenutil/screen_util.dart:92:52)
#8      ScreenUtil.setHeight (package:flutter_screenutil/screen_util.dart:113:44)
#9      SizeExtension.h (package:flutter_screenutil/size_extension.dart:8:32)
#10     RequestMitraView.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:gebu_client/app/modules/request_mitra/views/request_mitra_view.dart:105:75)
#11     Obx.build (package:get/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_obx_widget.dart:70:28)
#12     RxInterface.notifyChildren (package:get/get_rx/src/rx_types/rx_core/rx_interface.dart:26:27)
#13     _ObxState.build (package:get/get_state_manager/src/rx_flutter/rx_obx_widget.dart:54:19)
#14     StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4870:27)
#15     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:15)
#16     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#17     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)
#18     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4735:5)
#19     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4919:11)
#20     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4729:5)
...     Normal element mounting (33 frames)
#53     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3790:14)
#54     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3540:18)
#55     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1243:37)
#56     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1228:20)
#57     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2600:19)
#58     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.createChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1221:12)
#59     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:349:23)
#60     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1997:59)
#61     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:918:15)
#62     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1997:14)
#63     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._createOrObtainChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:338:5)
#64     RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.insertAndLayoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:484:5)
#65     RenderSliverList.performLayout.advance (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:239:19)
#66     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:281:12)
#67     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#68     RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:137:12)
#69     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:371:11)
#70     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1887:7)
#71     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:510:13)
#72     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1580:12)
#73     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1489:20)
#74     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1731:7)
#75     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:887:18)
#76     RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:497:19)
#77     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:883:13)
#78     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#79     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1144:15)
#80     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1081:9)
#81     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:995:5)
#85     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:151:10)
#86     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:308:5)
#87     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)`

i have no idea how to get this problem done.

Comment: you probably missed to "bind" and "put" your controller with that route